# Inheritance private method and public

Tags: java

Let 's say I have base class `A` and subclass `B` that extends it

Class `A` got:

```
protected int doStuff(List<String>list)
```

In `B` which method can override this method without errors?

```
protected long doStuff(List<String> l)
private int  doStuff(Collection<String> c)
public final int doStuff(List<String>l)
protected int doStuff(list1, l2)
```

I think it's the `public final` one but I'm not sure.

I had this question today in an exam

Comment: `protected` will also work.

Comment: so which answer? only one is correct of the 4

Comment: @bereal neither of the two `protected` methods is a valid override (first one has a broader return type, second one is an overload with an additional parameter, if only it compiles with untyped parameters)

Comment: only one should be correct

Comment: @ernest_k ah true, didn't pay attention to the args. So it's `public final` only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. `protected long doStuff(List<String> l)`

The returned type is different (`long` instead of `int`). This is not overwriting the initial method.

#### 2. `private int  doStuff(Collection<String> c)`

You can't reduce the visibility of the inherited method. Plus, the argument is different. This is not overwriting the initial method.

#### 3. `public final int doStuff(List<String> l)`

The returned type is the same, the argument type is the same. The method visibility is different, but as `public` visiblity is greater than `protected`, it will works. This is the correct answer.

#### 4. `protected int doStuff(list1, l2)`

The number of argument is different. This is not overwriting the initial method. (Note there is no type specified for the arguments, so this method prototype is also not valid.)